# Macro to export all n set of values combinations of x>n values of range

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to exports combinations from a range of many sets of values .
The sets of exporting combs will be smaler than the data range sets .
For examble lets say that i need all 2 set of values combinations of a 3 set of values in a data range .

DATA____ EXPORT

A B C____ AB AC BC

### B B A____ BB BA BA

-

All the values of the data will be in different cels each one but the combs values must be in one cell each time.
Also the exports must be in horizontial as the example .

This is a code that ifound on web little close for me , but i cannot edit this to use it .

```
enter code here

Sub comb()
Dim vElements As Variant, vresult As Variant
Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

vElements = Application.Transpose(Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)))
Columns("C:Z").Clear

lRow = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(vElements) 
ReDim vresult(1 To i)
Call CombinationsNP(vElements, i, vresult, lRow, 1, 1)
Next i
End Sub

Sub CombinationsNP(vElements As Variant, p As Long, vresult As Variant, lRow As Long,  

iElement As Integer, iIndex As Integer)                                                                                                      
Dim i As Long

For i = iElement To UBound(vElements)
vresult(iIndex) = vElements(i)
If iIndex = p Then
    lRow = lRow + 1
    Range("C" & lRow).Resize(, p) = vresult



Else
    Call CombinationsNP(vElements, p, vresult, lRow, i + 1, iIndex + 1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you very much and sorry for my english .

Comment: You really need to *try to write something*, and post your code (even if it doesn't work) along with a description of what problems you ran into.  Typically questions which just state a set of requirements - without any evidence you actually tried to come up with a solution - will get closed quite quickly here.

Comment: In order to help you along (and in case you were wondering what this problem is called), search for "vba string permutations" (or combinations) in google. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the replys guys.I forgot to say that i'm new in vba macros.Thats my new hobby .It is very difficult for me to write a code from the begining.I can only edit for my needs some simply codes that i found on the web .But for this project i have not find something close for what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it was more convenient to use a new Sheet/ Range with  cell reference

**((= Sheet1! $A1 & Sheet1! B1))**   ***this is three lines then copy***

Sub Sub export_01()

Dim aStart, aExport
  Dim aRow As Integer

```
 aRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
 aStart = 1
 aExport = 5

   For i = 1 To aRow

   Cells(i, aExport).Value = Cells(i, aStart) & Cells(i, aStart + 1)
   Cells(i, aExport + 1).Value = Cells(i, aStart) & Cells(i, aStart + 2)
   Cells(i, aExport + 2).Value = Cells(i, aStart + 1) & Cells(i, aStart + 2)
   Next i
```

End Sub()

Comment: Thamks Hatek for your reply.Your code exports exactly what iwant but only for small set of numbers.I can use it only if i know the combination placements and add them in your code manual .The problem is for a large set of combinations.For examble combinations of 6 values of 12.Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me simply use a second for loop

dim aStartend = 1

For i = 1 To aRow

```
For ii = 0 To 5  ' starts whist 0 to 5 = 6 time

  Cells(i, aExport+ii).Value = Cells(i, aStart) & Cells(i,aStartend + ii)
```

--
  --
    next ii

next i

Comment: Thanks again hatek for your reply.I steel belive that this code dosent works for me .I test it and that takes only the first value to combine with the rest .If it is something that icannot understand in your code is how to combine for example  6 set of values from 12 set of values(that means 924 combs)?Can you post all the code for this example?